# Google Search Appliance latest firmware download - 5.0.4

Tags: google-search-appliance

Does anyone know where i can find the lates bin file for version 5.0.4 firmware for the google search appliance (mini)?

Here is the latest patch: http://dl.google.com/enterprise/vm_patch_1_for_504_G22_and_G24_only.bin

Answer (score 2):

The Mini was discontinued around 2012.  The hardware is out of support and there is no software support.  The only places you would find this would not be authorized sources.